# Cant fetch detail of XMPPRoom from the server XMPP Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, xmppframework

I have created a MembersOnly, Persistant Room. In which I have invited multiple occupants.
Now I want to fetch detail of room for the user which was invited by creator.

I tried this code :

XMPP requirement :

```
<iq from='hag66@shakespeare.lit/pda'
id='ik3vs715'
to='coven@chat.shakespeare.lit'
type='get'>
<query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'/>
</iq>
```

iOS code to call the from iOS

```
NSXMLElement *query = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"query" xmlns:@"http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"];//

NSString *iqID = [[appDelegate xmppStream] generateUUID];

XMPPJID *jID = self.room.roomJID;
XMPPIQ *element = [XMPPIQ iqWithType:@"get" to:jID  elementID:iqID child:query];
[element addAttributeWithName:@"from" stringValue:[[[appDelegate xmppStream] myJID] full]];
[[appDelegate xmppStream] fetchInformationForGivenIQ:element];
```

This should provide me this kinda result :

```
<iq from='coven@chat.shakespeare.lit'
id='ik3vs715'
to='hag66@shakespeare.lit/pda'
type='result'>
<query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'>
<identity
    category='conference'
    name='A Dark Cave'
    type='text'/>
<feature var='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc'/>
<feature var='muc_passwordprotected'/>
<feature var='muc_hidden'/>
<feature var='muc_temporary'/>
<feature var='muc_open'/>
<feature var='muc_unmoderated'/>
<feature var='muc_nonanonymous'/>
</query>
</iq>
```

But I am getting this result :

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="result" id="some ID" from="Group-ID" to="My Full JabberID">
<query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info">
<feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info">
</feature>
</query>
</iq>
```

Can any one help me what I am doing wrong.

THanks in advance.

Comment: Few correction, I didnt even get the detail of Public room. If nonOwner access the detail as I suggested way, he is not able to fetch the detail. Please guide.

Comment: Check out first two sections in the answer at: [XMPPFramework - Implement Group Chat (MUC)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19268629/xmppframework-implement-group-chat-muc)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the room info , you can call the mothod on `XMPPRoom`

```
- (void)fetchConfigurationForm;
```

Then , get the room info in the room's Delegate method

```
- (void)xmppRoom:(XMPPRoom *)sender didFetchConfigurationForm:(NSXMLElement *)configForm;
```

Comment: Hi Dee, Thanks to reply. But I already did it.I tried to fetch roomDetail by fetchConfigurationForm but I got error. (didNotFetchConfigurationForm delegate method called and iq type is error). I think issue is with roles, affiliations, Privileges. Do you have any idea what type of Roles, Affiliations, and Privileges need to assign to invited user by which I will get room detail calling same fetchConfigurationForm method.

Comment: please read the doc [!XEP-0045](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#associations)

Comment: Hey, @NileshTripathi, I think you are getting errors while fetching configuration cause you are not joined to room (this is my current situation)
Fetching Details possible without joining the room