# iOS XMPPFramework: how to parse didReceiveIQ?

Tags: ios, xmppframework

I've looked at the following [XMPPFramework - Implement Group Chat (MUC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19268629/xmpp-ios-chat-client-implement-group-chat) and have been successfully getting the list of public chatrooms. The list is returned from the function - (BOOL)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveIQ:(XMPPIQ *)iq, and I am trying to parse the information to create a plist so my iOS client can display all the chat rooms available to join.

Here is the iq being returned:

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="result" from="conference.example.com" to="admin@example.com/2abb8426"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items"><item jid="test@conference.example.com" name="Test Room"/></query></iq>
```

My problem is that I don't know how to correctly parse the information being returned, can anyone guide me into xml parsing in this example? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lets take as an example the official XEP page (http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html) with the response:

```
<iq from='chat.shakespeare.lit'
    id='zb8q41f4'
    to='hag66@shakespeare.lit/pda'
    type='result'>
  <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items'>
    <item jid='heath@chat.shakespeare.lit'
          name='A Lonely Heath'/>
    <item jid='coven@chat.shakespeare.lit'
          name='A Dark Cave'/>
    <item jid='forres@chat.shakespeare.lit'
          name='The Palace'/>
    <item jid='inverness@chat.shakespeare.lit'
          name='Macbeth&apos;s Castle'/>
  </query>
</iq>
```

You can obtain the `query` element by doing:

```
NSXMLElement *queryElement = [iq elementForName:@"query" xmlns:@"http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items"];
```

Then you can iterate over the items:

```
    NSArray *items = [queryElement elementsForName:@"item"];
    for (NSXMLElement *i in items) {
        NSString *roomName = [i attributeStringValueForName:@"name"];
        NSString *jidString = [i attributeStringValueForName:@"jid"];
        XMPPJID *jid = [XMPPJID jidWithString:jidString];
    }
```