# How to enters in the chat room + xmpp?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, xmppframework

I am working on the Chat concept by using XMPP framework. I am successfully able to make connection with the server. Now my next step is to enter in the given room.

```
        NSXMLElement *presence = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"presence"];
        NSString *room = [@"myroom" stringByAppendingString:@"@app.xmpp.syn.in"];
        [presence addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:room];
        NSXMLElement *x = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"x" xmlns:@"http://jabber.org/protocol/muc"];
        NSXMLElement *history = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"history"];
        [history addAttributeWithName:@"maxstanzas" stringValue:@"50"];
        [x addChild:history];
        [presence addChild:x];
        XMPPIQ *iq = [XMPPIQ iq];
        [iq addChild:presence];
        [xmppStream sendElement:presence];
```

I have tried with the above code but it doesn't work. It doesn't go to following method.

```
- (void)sendElement:(NSXMLElement *)element
{
    if (element == nil) return;
    dispatch_block_t block = ^{ @autoreleasepool {
        if (state == STATE_XMPP_CONNECTED)
        {
            [self sendElement:element withTag:TAG_XMPP_WRITE_STREAM];
        }
        else
        {
            NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:XMPPStreamErrorDomain
                                                 code:XMPPStreamInvalidState userInfo:nil];
            [self failToSendElement:element error:error];
        }
    }};

    if (dispatch_get_specific(xmppQueueTag))
        block();
    else
        dispatch_async(xmppQueue, block);
}
```

I am implementing this very first time. May be I am wrong to enter in the MUC room. Please correct or suggest me with this issue.

Comment: @iPatel I have to just enter into room Its a static chat room at server end

Comment: ok.. i just put above link that i found from google otherwise i have not any experience with XMPP framework.. :) happy Coding :)

Comment: @Sudha This may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19268629/xmpp-ios-chat-client-implement-group-chat

Answer (score 0):

First of all, these lines are wrong:

```
    XMPPIQ *iq = [XMPPIQ iq];
    [iq addChild:presence];
```

The 3 stanzas XMPP uses are `<presence>`, `<message>` and `<iq>`. You send these as separate children of the XML `<stream:stream>`. Wrapping a presence in an iq makes no sense. But in your example code you're not using `iq` after doing this, so this probably is not what causes you problem.

Secondly, you should send your presence to a full JID, not a bare JID. A full JID is a jid that includes a resource, so `myroom@app.xmpp.syn.in/resource`, instead of `myroom@app.xmpp.syn.in`. What you specify as resource will be your nickname in the chat. See [Example 18 in XEP-0045](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#example-18). So instead, you should do something similar to:

```
    NSString *room = [[@"myroom" stringByAppendingString:@"@app.xmpp.syn.in"] stringByAppendingString:@"/nickname"];
    [presence addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:room];
```